# Need add a space before character in changing category of character?

Tags: tex-core, catcodes, grouping

At the bottom of page 307 of **The TeXbook**, it says

> TEX always reads the token following a constant before evaluating that constant.

So,

```
{\catcode‘\>=2 >
```

is different from

```
{\catcode\`>=2>
```

It is true, as
`` {\catcode`\>=2>hello\par ``
outputs

[image]

But if there is

```
\catcode`\<=1
```

before that, the result is changed. Such as

```
{\catcode`\>=2>hello\par
\catcode`\<=1
{\catcode`\>=2>hello\par
\bye
```

outputs

[image]

Why does

```
\catcode`\<=1
```

affects

```
{\catcode`\>=2>hello\par
```

Comment: It doesn't. If you comment out `\catcode`\<=1` you get the same output.

Comment: I think it is because TeX finds the closing group in the third line because of what is on the first line. It's the fact you've changed the catcode already which makes the difference. The third line is equivalent to `{\catcode`\>=2}hello\par` because `>` is end group when TeX looks for the matching end group.

Comment: @cfr But why does the third line work well? Isn't it should be the same as the first line?

Comment: No because you've changed the meaning. `>` is *already* end group when that line is read. On the first line, `>` still has its original meaning.

Comment: @cfr But the third line has redifined it, doesn't it? And what the exact definiton of `>`, is it `2` or `2>`?

Comment: You've made `>`  mean end group. So it means the same as `}`. That's what a category code of `2` means: an end of group character.

Comment: @cfr So, why does the first line ouput `?hello`? What is the `?` here?

Comment: So TeX reads the `>` before dealing with the constant `2`. `>` is just the code for outputting that particular punctuation mark. So TeX has already read that and looked up that meaning *before* the category code of `>` is set to 2. Hence, you get that for the first line. But when TeX reads the third line, the character after the `2` is end of group. Because that's what `>` now means because you changed it on the first line.

Comment: @cfr Since the third line is outputed right, so the definition of `>` of line one is right. If the definition of `>` is right, why are there a `?`  at the beginning of the first line?

Comment: Because that's just what `>` is supposed to produce in TeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see: if you try

```
\tt
{\catcode‘\>=2 >
\bye
```

you get `No pages of output.`

On the other hand, with

```
\tt
{\catcode`\>=2>
\bye
```

you get output, precisely “>” and

```
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### simple group (level 1) entered at line 3 ({)
### bottom level
```

The explanation is easy: in the second case, the character `>` is tokenized before the category code assignment is finalized, hence it has category code 12. The use of `\tt` is to avoid getting “¿” in output.

Actually `` \catcode`\<=1 `` affects nothing and you get the same output (and the same warning) without it.

I'll just use `h` and remove `\par` that serve no purpose and just complicates tha analysis:

```
{\catcode`\>=2>h{\catcode`\>=2>h
```

You have the following token list:

`{`<sub>1</sub> `|catcode|` `` ` ``<sub>12</sub> `|>|` `=`<sub>12</sub> `2`<sub>12</sub> `>`<sub>12</sub> `h`<sub>11</sub> `{`<sub>1</sub> `|catcode|` `` ` ``<sub>12</sub> `|>|` `=`<sub>12</sub> `2`<sub>12</sub> `>`<sub>2</sub> `h`<sub>11</sub>

Can you see the difference? The first `>` has catcode 12 for the reasons explained above, but the second one has category code 2, because the assignment ***has been*** performed. So the second assignment is actually performed in a group and has essentially no effect. But you also see that adding `` \catcode`\<=1 `` has no role whatsoever.

The output is “>hh” and the warning about the unclosed group is the same, because the initial `{`<sub>1</sub> isn't balanced, while the second one is, by `>`<sub>2</sub>.

**Side note**

The codes

```
\catcode`\>=2
\catcode`>=2
```

are completely equivalent when `>` has its standard category code 12. Escaping the character is a safety measure that's actually only needed when the character has category code 0, 5, 9, 14 or 15. For instance, you cannot assign active category code to `^^@` (byte 0) with

```
\catcode`^^@=13
```

because normally `^^@` has category code 9 (ignored). To the contrary

```
\catcode`\^^@=13
```

would do. In the `\obeylines` macro you'll find

```
\catcode`\^^M\active
```

for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks. 1. Why can `\tt` avoid getting "¿" in output? 2. How did you get  `{`1 `|catcode|` and so on  from log file? 3. Why should it be `\catcode'\>=2` not `\catcode'>=1`, that is why should use `\>` not just `>`? 4. In your last case, initial `{`1 is balanced by `>`2, so it shouldn't be warned. Why not balanced?

Comment: @Y.zeng The original Computer Modern Roman fonts are 7 bit and have `¿` in place of `>`. Not Computer Modern Typewriter, though. Anyway, I didn't look in the log file: I *know* how to guess the category codes. About the warning, you apparently forgot that you have another `{` in the code, didn't you?

Comment: Yes. You are all right. I know now. Thanks. But what about the third question?

Comment: @Y.zeng ``\catcode`\>=2`` and ``\catcode`>=2`` are completely equivalent.

Comment: So, why did the author add `\ ` in ``\catcode`\>=2``?

Comment: @Y.zeng With a back quote, of course, not a straight one. The `>` has taken category code 2, so it matches the initial `{` and the catcode assignment is forgotten because performed in a group, so the `>` after the first `hello` is the normal one.

Comment: Why add `\ ` before `>` in ``\catcode'\>=2``?

Comment: @Y.zeng I already explained why in the side note. Did you read it?

Comment: I see it now. How did you know the content of the side note?

Comment: @Y.zeng I studied the TeXbook. By myself.

Comment: Hope in one day I will be as good as you.

Answer (score 1):

```
{\catcode`\>=2>hello\par
\catcode`\<=1
{\catcode`\>=2>hello\par
\bye
```

`\catcode`<=1` is not relevant here. MWE:

```
{\catcode`\>=2>hello\par
{\catcode`\>=2>hello\par
\bye
```

When TeX reads the first line, `>` has its standard meaning, which is to produce a punctuation symbol. So because TeX reads the `>` *before* evaluating the `2` and changing the meaning of `>`, the punctuation is produced in the output stream.

TeX then evaluates the `2` and makes the category code change. That is, it changes the meaning of `>`. Then it continues with the line.

When TeX reads the next line, `>` no longer has that meaning. It now has category code `2`, so it is an end-of-group marker, like `}`. So when TeX reads it before evaluating the `2` this time, it reads it as the end of the group rather than an instruction to typeset something.

TeX then evaluates the `2` and makes the category change (which doesn't actually change anything). Then it continues with the line.

The second line is thus equivalent to

```
{\catcode`\>=2}hello\par
```

`>` produces ¿ by design, just as `Q` produces Q. That's just how you input that punctuation mark. In LaTeX, you get the same symbol with the default font encoding, which is no surprise as it is just the default TeX encoding (OT1). If you're using a later encoding, such as `T1`, you can produce the same symbol with `\textquestionmarkdown`.

That is, the reason `>` produces that particular symbol is just the same reason `\textquestionmarkdown` produces it: that's how TeX has been told to expand those tokens (`>` in the one case and a macro in the other).

To see this, try

```
>hello\par
{\catcode`\>=2>hello\par
{\catcode`\>=2>hello\par
\bye
```

It might be easier to rewrite Knuth's example to use something more familiar. Consider

```
{\catcode`\Q=2Qhello\par
{\catcode`\Q=2Qhello\par
\bye
```

[image: Knuth's example with a familiar Q]

Comment: There is another question. On the third line, when `\cat'\>=` is ran, why does the second `>` in the line three still has the definition of group? In this situation, should it wait the new definition?

Comment: @Y.zeng It can't, can it, if TeX reads it before evaluating the `2`? That's the point Knuth is making, isn't it? [Also, the definition isn't actually any different, but I don't know that's relevant.]

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. I will remember this.

Comment: @Y.zeng Try running Knuth's example with `Q` rather than `>` (or see edit above). It's exactly the same principle but without the `>` business, though note `>` does the same in LaTeX by default e.g. `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}>hello\end{document}` compiled with pdfLaTeX will produce the same symbol. If you switch to the `T1` encoding, you get `>` instead.

Comment: What is the `T1` here?

Comment: @Y.zeng It's a newer (but no longer new) font encoding. The font encoding determines which characters are available and which 'slot' they occupy. OT1 is the original text encoding. It had only 128 slots, so you could not have more than 128 characters in any font using that encoding. It basically says, such-and-such character is in slot 1, such-and-such character in slot 2 etc. In practice, the maximum number of characters is smaller because you have to use some slots for other things. `T1` is the 'Cork' or 'European' or 'EC' text encoding and has 256 slots.

Comment: Can I switch encoding system? II have never set that.

Comment: @Y.zeng See https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontinst/inputs/latinetx. This is not exactly the thing used when you load `T1`, but it is more explanatory. https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/utilities/fontinst/inputs/latinetx/t1.etx is a file designed to prepare a font for use with `T1` encoding in LaTeX. If you view the file, you'll see it specifies what should go in each slot in such a font.

Comment: @Y.zeng What do you typeset with? (Engine? Format?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149860/discussion-between-cfr-and-y-zeng).